# How do I use the artifactory REST api to search for artifacts by name since a specified date?

Tags: artifactory

I tried making a GET request to this url:

`https://artifactory.xxxxxx.com/artifactory/api/search/dates?dateFields=created&from=1675050197406&name=yyyyy-*.tgz/`

but I ran into this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "Item not found for id '2649778966'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language) (Artifactory Query Language) to search for artifacts in Artifactory by name and last modified date. Here is an example AQL query to search for artifacts with a name starting with "my-artifact" modified after Jan 1, 2022:

```
items.find(
  {
    "name": {"$match": "my-artifact*"},
    "$and": [
      {"modified": {"$gt": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}
    ]
  }
)
```